# Calling a second javascript function that is located in a different file

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script

I have created a HTML form within the google apps script environment. With two files one HTML file including the HTML form and the relevant CSS, and another form including my java script functions.

When the submit button is pressed it calls a function GetSelectedText(), which returns the selected text value of a selection input. This function is within the HTML page.

What I then want to happen is once the GetSelectedText() function is called to call another function projectData() passing over the collected input value from the GetSelectedText().
However it doesn't pass over the variable and in the log it just has 'null'.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
<script>
function GetSelectedText(){
    var e = document.getElementById("projectNoView");
    var result = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    projectData(result);
 }
 
</script>
```

```
function projectData(result) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('10jSs0uoHOgO9VZusCa0ApyXmqISsHqsubIfRXiRPcQg');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Projects Progress");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var search = result;
  var optionsHTML = "";
  var NICEIC = "0";
  
  Logger.log(search);
  for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[i][0] == search){ 
    var NICEIC = sheet.getRange((i+1), 3).getDisplayValue();
      optionsHTML += '<input id = "mytext" name = "NICEIC" type = "text" placeholder="NICEIC" value="' + NICEIC + '" tabindex="2">' 
    }
  }; 
  return optionsHTML;
}
```

Comment: Either put all of your functions and css and html in one html file or use [templated html](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) which get's preloaded at the server.

Comment: You need to use [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) to call a server-side function (e.g. `google.script.run.projectData(result)`).

Comment: It's calling the function but its not passing the variable 'result' over to it.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Client-side functions cannot directly call server-side functions.

Comment: Yeah as in the second function above if I replace the 'search' variable with a string value that I know is in the table, it works

Comment: @Cooper, could you give an example of that please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server side functions can't be called directly from the client side code, you have to use `google.script.run` to do that. Example from the Google Apps Script guides

Server side code (Code.gs)

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function doSomething() {
  Logger.log('I was called!');
}
```

Client side code (Index.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      google.script.run.doSomething();
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Reference

- [HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)